# React - order of mounting/unmounting and figuring out how to implement a 'chain of responsibility'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have a keypress watcher, `document.addEventListener('keyup', ...` -- it's set to watch for keypresses across the document unless I'm inside an Input, Select or Textarea.

Now generally speaking, If I have a component A which contains component B which contains component C, in my architecture I would want C to have control of what happens on keyup, and when C is unmounted I would want to give that control to B, and when B is unmounted I would want to give that control to A -- the deepest-mounted element which has a keywatcher should control it.

So my idea was essentially this: When A mounts, define the keywatchers for A and set them -- when B mounts, define the keywatchers for B BUT SAVE the keywatchers for A so that when B unmounts, you can set the keywatchers back to what A had, and when C mounts, do the same -- set them for C but save the ones in B

But this all very much relies on the order that mounting and unmounting happens, and it turns out my assumptions were very wrong

```
import React from 'react';
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

@autobind
export class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showA: true
        }
    }

    hideA() {
        this.setState({showA:false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <div>

                    {this.state.showA
                        ? <A onClose={this.hideA}/>
                        : null}

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

@autobind
class A extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this should run 1st');
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('this should run 6th');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>element A</h3>
                <B onClose={this.props.onClose}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

@autobind
class B extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this should run 2nd');
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('this should run 5th');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>element B</h3>
                <C onClose={this.props.onClose}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

@autobind
class C extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this should run 3rd');
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('this should run 4th');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>element C</h3>
                <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>CLOSE A B C</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

I ran the above test, with the assumptions console.logging, and it turns out I got it entirely backwards -- it doesn't log 1,2,3 (button press) 4,5,6 -- it logs 3 2 1 (button press) 6 5 4

So my idea of writing a higher-level component which would take responsibility on mount and restore responsibility on unmount cannot work the way I wanted. Am I doing this the wrong way? Can I get some guidance?

Comment: "when C is unmounted I would want to give that control to B" why? this seems overly complicated. If, say, your search box component is unmounted you should kill the listener, not "move it up"

Comment: Well, for example, say I have a component B that is for an 'order', and when B is open I want the keywatcher to watch for Product Barcodes, but INSIDE B I can optionally open a Search box, which we'll call component C, and when C is open -- just temporarily open, it's only open for the duration of the search -- I no longer want B's Product Barcode keywatcher to work, I want Search to use its keywatcher instead with its own logic -- but as soon as the Search component is closed, I want B's keywatcher to start working again.

Comment: you're more likely to get a better response to this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or reddit or somewhere else

Comment: @DanielLizik Please don't recommend code that doesn't work the way the OP intends to go to Code Review. They are off-topic there.